Could not determine the dependencies of task ':lintVitalRelease'
I have been trying to export a game to android in the Godot Engine 3.2.2 but it throws this error  when I try to export the game. It was export the Apk fine before I configured it to do a custom build in the export properties
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':lintClassPath'.
   > Could not load module metadata from /home/aiden/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.71/descriptors/com.squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/f82a8259340803bc58fb8c686ca12ad9/descriptor.bin



BUILD FAILED in 12s

Exit Code: 1```
Do I have to clear the gradle cache or there is another way around build error

